# How To, Tweet Button sample code help?

Tags: javascript, button, twitter

i'm trying to implement a Tweet Button from this page http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button

and it looks like ti doesn't working very well for me. if my website is www.xxx.com the script should be:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fxxx" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
```

the graphics load but the count is 0.

i don't understand what could be wrong.
any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I might pick a different example URL... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, using jQuery

```
<img id="tweetButton" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Share this on Twitter" src="http://a3.twimg.com/a/1294785484/images/goodies/tweetn.png" />

$("#tweetButton").click(function () {
            window.open("http://twitter.com/share?url=xxx", "tweet", "status=0,toolbar=0,width=500,height=300");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to go register for this feature on the twitter developers site. Once you do that it should generate some sort of number or code for you to put on your page that will link everything together and start counting as it should.

Comment: The Tweetbutton does not require any kind of registration.